# Выбор языка

Tags: c#, delphi, java

Здравствуйте!

Я не могу определиться между Java и C# (я около 1.5 лет писал на Delphi, немного знаком с  Си, месяца 3 писал на php, но веб мне до тошноты не нравится). С одной стороны я не хочу быть привязным к ОС, а с другой стороны я хочу разрабатывать десктопные приложения (как на Delphi). Просмотрев рынок предложений я понял, что у Java разработчика только 2 пути это либо веб (JavaEE), либо Android (JavaME).

Я на распутье...

Comment: да здравствует очередной холивар, сколько уже тем за последний месяц было как я тут)

android=JavaME???

Comment: Минусую, однозначного ответа не может быть, неконкретно, а также, как сказал предыдущий оратор, дубликат бесчисленных подобных вопросов.

Comment: Открыл заново. Считаю что вопрос имеет право на жизнь. Пусть холивар - ничего страшного. В споре ведь рождается истина!

Comment: Правильный ответ -- оба. Языки довольно близкие. А лучше -- Scala и F#

Comment: В C# (и Visual Studio) из Delphi перекочевало множество идей (свойства, события, индексаторы, концепция RAD), так как у этих языков один главный разработчик -- Андерс Хейлсберг, который в свое время переметнулся из Borland в Microsoft. Так что есть смысл перейти на C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы рекомендовал посмотреть внутрь себя - что нравится? Ведь сами уже сказали, что PHP/Веб не нравится до тошноты.

Посмотрите внимательно на C# и Java попишите пару прог и поймете что вам больше нравится.

Причина почему надо выбирать то что нравится проста: если вам предмет нравится у вас автоматически появляется конкурентное преимущество - вы будете лучше знать тот язык который вам нравится, а не тот который вынуждены учить в силу обстоятельств. А раз лучше будете знать - соответственно и дороже будете стоить.

Удачи в выборе.

Comment: спасибо за совет, наверное так я и поступлю

Answer (score 12):

Java не учить С#

Comment: А где запятую ставить?
"Java, не учить С#" или "Java не учить, С#" :)

Comment: Капитан Очевидность detected. Даже три. :)

Comment: Тонкий троллинг :)

Comment: Казнить нельзя помиловать

Answer (score 0):

ну раз 1,5 года на Delphi почему бы вам не воспользоваться Delphi XE2 И кросплатформенность есть (правда сыровато немного но излечимо) или Lasarus.

И еше мне почемуто Ruby понравился (Не путайте с ruby on rails)

Answer (score 0):

Мне после 3 лет delphi легче всего дался C#.
У этого языка большие перспективы: Планшеты, Телефоны, ПК. Также если потребуется программирование игр в Unity 3D в основном идут C# скрипты.
Но есть и другой вариант ждать Delphi4Android.

Comment: ??? говорили про шарп, а закончили вообще дельфей4андроид. Это вообще про что было @Monax?

Answer (score 0):

Я тоже года два писал на Delphi, но когда начал изучать C# - WPF понял, что Delphi и рядом не лежал, всё делается намного проще; про Java не знаю, не писал, но по моему скромному мнению лучше изучать C# / WPF.